# History issue combining WP7.5, phonegap and jqm

Tags: windows-phone-7, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have a phonegap app that uses jqm that works fine in android and ios.

Porting to WP7 i have an issue with the history, specifically **history.back()** (but also **.go(-1)** etc). This refers to going back in history where the previous 'page' was in the same physical html file, just a different **data-role=page** div.

using a jwm site in a regular browser is fine (with separate 'pages' in the same html file). Also, using history.back() when we go from one html file to another in the app is fine. It's the specific combination of WP7.5, jqm and PG.

Has anyone come across a solution for this? it's driving me crazy, and has been as issue since PG 1.4.1 and jwm 1.0.

EDIT 1: It's possible that the phonegap process of initialising the webview on WP7.5 somehow overrides the jqm history overrides, after they've loaded.

EDIT 2: definitely something to do with jqm not being able to modify the history. each time there is a 'page' change, history.length is still 0.

EDIT 3: When i inspect the 'history' object, i found there is no function for **replaceState** or **pushState** - i know jqm uses this for history nav, maybe that's the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok - this isn't perfect, but here's a solution (read: hack) that works for me. It **only** works for page hash changes, not actual url changes (but you could add a regex check for that). Put this somewhere in the code that runs on **ondeviceready**:

```
if (device.platform == 'WinCE') {
    window.history.back = function () {
        var p = $.mobile.urlHistory.getPrev();
        if (p) {
            $.mobile.changePage("#" + p.pageUrl, { reverse: true });
            $.mobile.urlHistory.stack.splice(-2, 2);
            $.mobile.urlHistory.activeIndex -= 2;
        }
    }
}
```